# как связать sys.objects и sys.server_principals?

Tags: sql, sql-server

В `sys.objects` есть поле `schema_id` и `principal_id`, отсюда можно узнать пользователя, которому объект принадлежит. А как отсюда найти `login` этого пользователя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Связь через столбец `sid`:

```
SELECT d.name AS 'UserName', 
       s.name AS 'LoginName'
FROM sys.database_principals d
     LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals s ON d.sid = s.sid;
```